# Laravel: convert multidimensional array to collection

Tags: laravel, multidimensional-array, collections

In my project I have a dynamic form of the following structure:

```
- Date 1
  - Shift 1
    - Area 1
      - Cell 1
      - Cell 2
    - Area 2
      - Cell 3
      - Cell 4
  - Shift 2
    - Area 1
      - Cell 1
  ...
```

I take data from inputs with the following multidimensional array: data[index][column], where a column may be: date, shift, area, cell, or cell content.

Then I need to store this form into database to be able to recreate it later. It's easy, because my array has a table form:

```
index | Date  | Shift | Area | Cell | Cell Content
1       05.06   1       1       1         100
2       05.06   1       1       2         99
3       05.06   1       2       3         55
4       05.06   1       2       4         66
5       05.06   2       1       1         35
```

But when to recreate the form (take it back from the database), it would be better to convert this array into a collection, to be able to do the following foreach:

```
foreach (dates as date)
  foreach (date->shifts as shift)
    foreach (shift->areas as area)
      foreach (area->cells as cell)
         echo cell->content
      endforeach
    endforeach
  endforeach
endforeach
```

Is it possible in Laravel? Or I need to use the old method: comparison current element with precedent and break the for when different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see here is that all the columns are stored in the same table i.e. you have a denormalized structure. A simple solution would be to normalize your data (might come with a cost) and then defining the relations would be very simple in Laravel.

So I suggest you split your single table into :

- dates (id, date)
- shifts (id, date_id, shift)
- areas (id, shift_id, area)
- cells (id, area_id, cell)

Now you can also choose to have redundant data and add shift_id and date_id to your cell table. If saving space is not your concern, maybe store data in both the ways.

Read more about normalization https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/database-normalization-normal-forms/

Comment: Yes, u are right. I have redundant data in this table. Need to think more bout it.